# generate dynamic pie chart and page redirection in mvc2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I want to know how to generate a pie chart dynamically. and how to redirect a page to another  web page?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Silverlight for the pie chart, it is very good for those and dynamic.

for redirecting the page, if the page you want to redirect to is a View which is rendered by an action method, you can redirect to that action and it will redirect the page to its corresponding view after doing its magic:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(int id)
{
    // Do your things here

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**EDIT:** Yes, that's why I told you to use Silverlight :), to get started, you need to check [Silverlight Charting Toolkit](https://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl2/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html) and here's a [video on Pie Chart](http://silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/silverlight-toolkit-pie-chart/)

Comment: thx a lot . but can you also tell me how to generate a pie chart dynamically using mvc2 as we cannot use any controls other than html controls